# Изучение java

Tags: java

Хочу начать изучать java, какие книги, уроки посоветуете?

Comment: Быть программистом, не означает знать все. Ведь очень часто приходится писать спицефические программы: бугалтерия, медецина, итд итп. Никто не сможет покрыть знаниями все сферы. Поэтому умение искать нужную информацию является одним из наиболее важных для программиста :)

p.s. Учитесь пользоватся поиском! На этот вопрос отвечали много раз, в том числе и на этом форуме

Comment: можно я буду минусовать такие вопросы? спасибо.

Answer (score 10):

- Кей Хорстманн. Java 2 (двухтомник)
- Брюс Эккель. Философия Java
- Джошуа Блох. Java. Эффективное программирование

Лучше всего в оригинале и в таком порядке.

Comment: Джошуа Блох. Java. Эффективное программирование
хорошая книга, чем-то напоминается книги Мейерса по плюсам "Effective C++"

Answer (score 5):

Я сначала учил по Г. Шилдт "java руководство для начинающих",
сейчас изучаю Head First Java, O`Reilly(очень нравиться, хорошо написана),
 также под рукой находятся книги Кея Хорстманна "Java 2" оба тома. 
  Так же прохожу курс молодого бойца на blackbeltfactory.com классный ресурс =)
+ ещё javatalks.ru (может помочь в решении некоторых вопросов)

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/ как же я мог забыть про оснвную документацию)))

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас читаю Хорстманна. Java 2 (двухтомник) 1ый том. Книжка достаточно неплохая, очень хорошие, примеры, очень подробные, но у меня есть некоторый бекграунд на плюсах, мне немного проще. Там есть так называемые сравнения с C++, постоянно приводятся. А так классная книга. Плюс посоветовал бы смотреть видео уроки еще.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы добавить книгу Г. Шилдта "Java полное руководство". (немного полезной информации также есть в [блоге](http://www.jdevel.ru)).

В комментариях к первому ответу упоминали Джошуа Блоха - его книгу лучше читать на английском. А так, инет + практика лучше многих книг, ну и конечно тематические форумы. Удачи в изучении!